# obter o id de uma tag a gerada dinamicamente

Tags: div, table

Bom dia.

Alguém sabe dizer como faço em jquery pra capturar alguns dados de uma tag a dentro de uma **tabela gerada dinamicamente**? Na verdade tudo dentro da div "showPesqReserva" é gerado dinamicamente.

Ex:

```
<div id="showPesqReserva">
   <div id="calendar">
       <table id="tabela">
           <tr>
              <td><a role="button" class="dayReserve" data-dia="2016-01-15" data-local="sala1" data-horario="17:30">15</a></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Estou fazendo desta forma mas não está dando certo. Não gera erro e não acontece nada ao clicar:

```
$("#tabela").on("click", "a", function(event){
    var iData = $(this).data("dia");
    var iLocal = $(this).data("local");
    var iHorario = $(this).data("horario");
    event.prevendDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "fazalgumacoisa.php",
       data: "dia="+iData + "&espaco="+iLocal + "&horas="+iHorario,
       dataType: "html",
       ...
    })
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressupondo que sua `div` esteja dentro da tag `body` do seu html e que você já possuí a biblioteca jquery incluída no código, Faça o seguinte:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("body").delegate(".dayReserve", "click", function(e){
        //Retirando ação padrão já no início do código.
        e.preventDefault()

        var iData = $(this).data("dia");
        var iLocal = $(this).data("local");
        var iHorario = $(this).data("horario");

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "fazalgumacoisa.php",
           data: "dia="+iData + "&espaco="+iLocal + "&horas="+iHorario,
           dataType: "html",
           ...
        })
        return false;
    });
})

</script>
```

O `.delegate()` vai permitir que outros links gerados dinamicamente sem refresh tbm possam ser clicados. Você pode usar o `.live()` também.

Lembrando que o seu código jQuery deve sempre ficar dentro de `$(document).ready(function(){...});` OU  `$(function(){...});`
Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Olá Thomas. Agora deu certo! Muito obrigado mesmo. já tinha tentado de tudo.

Comment: Vlw @Francisco!